# JSON multi-dimensional array for Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

Any ideas if it is possible to serialize HTML fields which are in a multi-dimensional array format for transmission over AJAX post?

Tried serializeArray and that formats 1 level of the array.

Data I need to serialize would be a series of name/value fields e.g.

```
name="customer" value="the value"
name="location" value="the location"
```

Using serializeArray() works fine on these e.g.

```
var formData = $('#createVacancy :input');
var serializedFormData = formData.serializeArray();
```

But some of the form data uses HTML array notation e.g.

```
name="tier[1][tiers][5][groupId]" value="5"
```

Result from serializeArray()

Normal name/value pairs comes through like Object `{ name="customer_name", value="Test customer name"}`

But fields which use html array notation come through like:

```
Object { name="tier[1][publication_date]", value="03 Feb 2011"}, 
Object { name="tier[1][publication_date_db]", value="2011-02-03"}, 
Object { name="tier[1][tiers][5][groupId]", value="5"}, 
Object { name="tier[1][tiers][5][groupName]", value="Diamond"}
```

I'd have though this would need to be broken down into further objects.

Comment: can you example what you want to serialize

Comment: What is the reason for herarchy in field names ? Is it your HTML structure, how you want to be passes - Is it all tiers # needed ?

Comment: The hierarchy is dynamically generated with jQuery so to keep a logical order when submitting the form I use the html structure above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `JSON.stringify` method from [json2.js](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

try JSON_decode http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: It's prior to the Ajax call I need this. In essence I need to obtain all form fields and formulate a Json string for transmission to a Php file where I will then use Json_decode.

Comment: show example of "HTML fields which are in a multi-dimensional array"